# Unable to debug native applications with ndk-gdb. Running start command gives error: "Could not extract package's data directory"

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk

I am using the android NDK version 10e, and I am trying to debug a purely native piece of code using ndk-gdb.  However every time I run "ndk-gdb start", I get the following:

ERROR: Could not extract package's data directory. Are you sure that
          your installed application is debuggable

I have reproduced this with one of the code samples that the ndk ships with itself.  The sample is in sample/native-activity.  The only change I made was to add **android:debuggable="true"** to the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I created a project of the sample and compiled it using: **ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1**

I have an attached Nexus 9 Running Android 5.1.1.  It shows up just find with adb devices:

```
List of devices attached
HT4BEJT03561    device
```

I have enabled developer mode, and under developer options I have turned on "USB Debugging".

So what is going wrong here?  Can these native applications be debugged?

Comment: How do you build your app? Are you using Android Studio with the *experimental* gradle plugin? I believe they discontinued GDB, and now only LLDB is available.

Comment: No, I am still using eclipse (MARS) with the ADT